# Python parsing multiple url into array from XML

Tags: python, arrays, xml

I would like to extract multiple urls from a node and place them into a string array.  Currently I'm saving all the text from the desired node into a string;

```
imgsUrl= value.text
```

then I am parsing the string and getting the correct url.

```
imgsUrl[imgUrl.find("http://"):imgUrl.find(".JPG")+4]
```

My issue with this is there could be 1-200 urls I need from imgsUrl, and I'm only able to obtain one of them.  Is there a good solution to place all of them into an array that would be less tedious?

sample input:

```
sampleStr="<ul><li><a href="http://website/abc/vcd/HHD00300.JPG">HHD00300.JPG</a></li>
<li><a href="http://website/abc/vcd//HHD003002.jpg">HHD003002.jpg</a></li></ul>"
```

output:

```
print imgUrlSubString
outputs this:  http://website/abc/vcd//HHD003000.JPG
```

expected output:

```
['http://website/abc/vcd//HHD003000.JPG','http://website/abc/vcd//HHD003002.JPG',....]
```

Comment: Can you post a sample input and the expected output?

Comment: Regex should do the trick. See [this][1] answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6883094/447599

Comment: @vikramls alright sample input with corresponding output has been included

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python xml ElementTree from a string source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647071/python-xml-elementtree-from-a-string-source)

Comment: @Julius This seems to work great.  Is this a similar approach that niroyb mentioned below? If so, I'd like to mark one of these as the answer. thanks!

Comment: vikramls answer is a better practice. however, the one I mentionned and niroyb are the same, and definitely would have worked in that context, and I really think that a true software engineer should know regex really well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer - I used lxml.html to parse the HTML. It is generally a bad idea to use regexes to parse HTML (see @ivan_pozdeev's answer above).

```
import lxml.html

sampleStr='<ul><li><a href="http://website/abc/vcd/HHD00300.JPG">HHD00300.JPG</a></li><li><a href="http://website/abc/vcd//HHD003002.jpg">HHD003002.jpg</a></li></ul>'
html = lxml.html.fromstring(sampleStr)
print html.xpath('//a/@href')
```

The code uses an `xpath` expression to retrieve all the `href` properties in all `a` tags in the string `sampleStr`.

#### Sample output:

```
['http://website/abc/vcd/HHD00300.JPG', 'http://website/abc/vcd//HHD003002.jpg']
```

Comment: Is it still possible to access html like an array, for example...print html[0] would print 'http://website/abc/vcd//HHD003000.JPG'

Comment: Yes, you would store the expression like this: `href_list = html.xpath('//a/@href')` and you now have a list `href_list` which you can iterate over or access directly using `href_list[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) method.
It returns all non overlapping regular expression matches directly in a list.

```
print( re.findall("http://.*?\.JPG", imgsUrl) )
```

Using ".*?" instead of ".*" is important in this case because there can be multiple urls so you want the non greedy match.

The best way to go though is to use an xml parser.
For python, beautifulsoup and lxml are pretty popular.

See these answers:

- [retrieve links from web page using python and beautiful soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautiful-soup)
- [python lxml/beautiful soup to find all links on a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131089/python-lxml-beautiful-soup-to-find-all-links-on-a-web-page)
- [get all the links of HTML using lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383383/get-all-the-links-of-html-using-lxml)

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/648265 at once. And each time you'll think of providing such an answer ever again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse this string.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(sampleStr)
links = soup.find_all("a")
output = []
for link in links:
    output.append(link["href"])
```

And here's the output:

```
print(output)
>>> ['http://website/abc/vcd/HHD00300.JPG', 'http://website/abc/vcd//HHD003002.jpg']
```

Comment: Thanks, this method also works for my problem.  Not sure if there's a better choice but both work, thanks a lot!